# Nested repeater will not display bound information from list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get a page to display information in a row layout using repeaters. I have one working that allows me to dynamically create hyperlinks, however i cant get my nested repeater to work to display the date the file was created. Is it possible to use repeaters to dynamically display multiple variables from lists as i'm trying to do below?

.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater id="repLinks" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr><td>

      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString().Split('\\').Last() %>"  />    

            <td>  

               <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound" >
                  <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Container.DataItem.ToString()%>  
                     </ItemTemplate> 
               </asp:Repeater>             
           </td>

           <td>
               Submitted By <!--add repeater-->
           </td>
           <td>
               Mark as Billed <!--add repeater-->
           </td>
           </td></tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
```

.aspx.cs

```
public List<string> CD = new List<string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Welcomes User
        string Uname = Environment.UserName;
        UserName.Font.Size = 17;
        UserName.Text = "Welcome: " + Uname;

        //gives path and constructs lists for directory paths and file links
        string root = "C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites";
        List<string> lLinks = new List<string>();

        //adds files to list
        foreach (var path in Directory.GetDirectories(@root))
        {
            foreach (var path2 in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                lLinks.Add(path2);

                CD.Add(File.GetCreationTime(path2).Date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd"));
            }
        }

        //Define your list contents here 
        repLinks.DataSource = lLinks;
        repLinks.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater Repeater2 = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2"));
            Repeater2.DataSource = CD;
            Repeater2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are binding the nested repeater control (Repeater2) in the `ItemDataBound` event of `Repeater2` repeater itself which will never get fired because `ItemDataBound` event is fired for each item in collection when it is bounded to the repeater control.

You should write the logic in `ItemDataBound` event of your parent repeater like this:-

```
<asp:Repeater id="repLinks" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
```

Then, write the logic in this event handler:-

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
                                      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
        Repeater Repeater2 = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2"));
        Repeater2.DataSource = CD;
        Repeater2.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Also, In the `Page_Load` event you should bind the Parent Repeater `Repeater1` on just the initial page load so wrap it inside `!IsPostBack` and populate your datasource `lLinks` & `CD` from a separate method intead of doing it in Page_Load event.